# Elasticsearch getting the last nested or most recent nested element

Tags: elasticsearch

We have this mapping:

```
{
    "product_achievement": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
            "id": {
                "type": "long"
            },
            "last_purchase": {
                "type": "long"
            },
            "products": {
                "type": "long"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you see this is nested, and the `last_purchase` field is a `unixtimestamp` value. We would like to query from all nested elements the most recent entry defined by the `last_purchase` field AND see if in the last entry there is some product id is in products.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using a `nested` query with [`inner_hits`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-inner-hits.html#nested-inner-hits). In the query part, you can specify the product id you want to match and then using `inner_hits` you can sort by decreasing `last_purchase` timestamp and only take the first one using `size: 1`

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "product_achievement",
      "query": {
        "term": {
          "product_achievement.products": 1
        }
      },
      "inner_hits": {
        "size": 1,
        "sort": {
          "product_achievement.last_purchase": "desc"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Actually I think we want something slightly different. We want first to pick the last entry, then see if in the last entry the product id is in. This in words means, find out the last order, and see if the last ordered item is product id 1.

Comment: Then you should be able to use the same nested query, but instead of `term`, you can use `"match_all": {}`

Comment: `inner_hits` is experimental, is there a way to get these in other ways?

Comment: If you don't want to use `inner_hits`, you can get the full array of nested `product_achievement` elements and then take either the first or last element. For this, you have to make sure, though, that your list of achievements is properly sorted at indexing time.

Comment: what's the syntax to get the last element?

Comment: That's the thing. Without `inner_hits`, you can't, you have to retrieve the full array, parse it on the client side and then take the last element from your array. I wouldn't be too worried about inner_hits going away though, even though that's flagged as experimental.